# Android device (phone/tablet) that has a display that can be easily viewed in direct sunlight

Tags: android, smartphones, tablet, displays

I am looking for an Android device that has a display that can be easily viewed in direct bright sunlight.  I have tried several high-end cell phones, and they are all challenging to read in bright sunlight.  Might need something with a reflective display.

- The screen size needs to be at least 12.5cm (5"), and can be up to
  30cm (12").  Prefer something around 20cm (8").
- Prefer a color screen, but black and white is acceptable.
- The device *must* have a GPS.
- Lower cost is strongly preferred, although I do not have a specific
  budget in mind.
- The Android version that it runs needs to be KitKat or later.
- Water resistance is a big plus.  Will be used outdoors.
- Brand does not matter.
- Does not need to have telephone function (can be a phone or a tablet).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be looking more at e-readers than phones/tablets.

Something like this perhaps? https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Professional-cheap-13-3-Boox-Max_60538385575.html?spm=a2700.7724857.main07.10.75b367af4LveAr&s=p